# package outliers won't knit on R markdown

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit the following code, that works perfectly on my console, in an R markdown file. However, I can't knit it because the function scores isn't recognized (part of the package outliers, which is correctly installed). Any ideas on how to knit something from a downloaded package?
Thank you!

[image: code and error message]

Comment: Did you call `library(outliers)` before that?

Comment: I did, it put out the same error.